# How to wait for an event from a specific element in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright

How do I wait for an event on a specific element in Playwright? Like `page.waitForEvent` ([docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-event)) but from a specific element only, not the whole page.

Comment: What event? How are you triggering the event? Please provide details, preferably a website and the primary goal you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What event: any event of arbitrary type. How trigger: the element itself will emit the event for any arbitrary reason. Primary goal: wait for the event to be emitted.

Comment: Can you pick an example event the element is going to emit? I'm not sure what this would be.

Comment: `'valueChange'`, `'error'`, `'checkedChange'`, `'selectChange'`, `'openChange'`: any arbitrary event type.

Comment: OK, so what does this do for your application? What's your [underlying goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)? I guess you could install an event listener on the element and use `waitForFunction` but usually, you'd use a `waitForFunction` directly and monitor the value changing, cutting out the middle man. So the specific event you're listening for matters, as does your use case, since there is probably a very direct way to achieve whatever your fundamental goal is.

Comment: Good points. In this case I truly just want to wait for an event to be emitted. `waitForFunction` looks promising, but it's only on the `Page` object, not on `Locator` or `ElementHandle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the [`Locator.evaluate`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-evaluate) method:

```js
const myLocator = page.locator('my-element').first();
await myLocator.waitFor();

const myEvent = await myLocator.evaluate((element) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        element.addEventListener('<event-type-here>', (event) => {
            return resolve(event);
        });
    });
});
```